# Cannot add service based database in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio

As described above, whenever I go to add new item, select Service Based Database and hit ok, I get the below error.

[The error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qrTs.png)

I've made sure SQL Server Express is installed and the Database workspace is installed for VS.

Is there something simple I'm missing here? I've looked for hours and can't find any fix.

Comment: Is the service (SQLServer) running?

Comment: you shouldn't rely on the ide(VS) to create/manage the database.

Answer (score -1):

Try running services.msc and to open Services and check if Sql Server (Sqlexpress) service is running.